# I am working on Android marquee of images. I implemented AutoSlider but can't call an activity

Tags: java, android

I am working on Android marquee of images. I implemented AutoSlider but am not able to call an activity. Below is my Autoslider code.
I am developing an application where I need an image floating from the left side of screen to the right side of screen. Can anybody help me?  How can I float some image from the left to right or vice versa? The Image should float like a marquee, as in HTML. They should start from the left side and end at right side of the screen. I want something similar in Android.

```
    package com.hp.smartedi.activities;

    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    import com.hp.smartedi.R;

    public class Autoslider extends LoginActivity{
            public int currentimageindex=0;
            Timer timer;
            TimerTask task;
            ImageView slidingimage;

            int[] IMAGE_IDS = {R.drawable.splash_se};

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

                // Create runnable for posting
                final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        AnimateandSlideShow();

                    }
                };

                int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.

                int period = 8000; // repeat every 4 sec.

                Timer timer = new Timer();

                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                public void run() {

                     mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);

                }

                }, delay, period);

            }

            public void onClick(View v) {

                finish();
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
              }
               private void AnimateandSlideShow() {

                slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.app);
                slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);

                currentimageindex++;

              }


    }
```

Please help me: how should I call the AutoSlider in my LoginActivity?

Comment: you want floating images on your LoginActivity?

Comment: No I want the AutoSlider to be called in LoginActivity

Comment: so if i got you right, you want to call another activity from LoginActivity?